Ubuntu 24.10 remote access and audio
Host OS windows 11 and hyper-V
Guest OS ubuntu 24.10 with remote login (RDP) enabled
connected using windows 11 mstsc.
No audio device found on Guest OS ubuntu 24.10
Identified that there is a complex solution that involves installing xrdp.

Does this mean the native remote login should be disabled?

Is there any other approach that is simple to setup that works with the native remote login?


Has ubuntu identified this as an issue? Surely support for hyper-v hosts might be a priority?
